# text encoding in .net

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, character-encoding

I am importing terms from a DB that contain foreign characters of all kinds. When I have japanese characters or chinese, I cannot run an update statement on the table since it cannot match the terms;

```
sqlUpdate = "Update QueryData set LastSearchDate ='" & DateTime.Now.ToString & "'" & " 

where QueryTerms = '" & item & "'"
```

item is the search terms and it works fine for all other characters except when it is japanese. Now if I did it in sql server 2005 I would have to put an N in front of the term to find a match.

```
select * from QueryData where queryTerms =N'だしの素'
```

Is there a way to check a strings encoding in .net so that I can then encode it before running the query or is there an equivalent to the N in .net
there has to be a more easier way of handling this.

Comment: What is the encoding of the database set to?

Comment: the column for the queryterms is nvarchar and the collation is sql-latin1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite possible that using parameterized queries here will simply sort out your problem - as well as not being vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Keep your data (the query value) away from your code (the SQL) - that way you don't have to represent everything as a string, which avoids all kinds of issues.

See the docs for [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example of how to use parameterized queries.

Comment: Exactly what I was tempted to answer when seeing that there were no answers, but then I figured "I'll let Jon take this one".

Comment: @Bergius: You never know... one day someone will ask a question like this (or maybe one on parameter passing) *and I'll decide not to reply*. Maybe I'll go outside and skip along in the fresh air or something, quite possibly singing a rousing Broadway showtune, encouraging the passers-by to join me in throwing off the shackles of modern life.

Comment: I'm confident that you can do the skipping, singing, encouraging AND answering of SO questions at the same time.